# Sliding 'Edit Box' for jquery Portlet

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery portlets in my web application. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets

What I want to do is make a Edit-Box appear between the Portlet header and Portlet Content once user clicks on the 'Settings' icon present on every Portlet-Header.
I can achieve this by having separate Edit-box for every individual Portlet.
But my question is how do I achieve this when I have a common 'Edit-Box' that is shared between all the Portlets present on my web-page.
How do I make this edit box appear between the 'Header & Content' Part after user clicks on the 'Settings' icon of that particular portlet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually create an edit box on the fly, I mean when you click on the setting button.
Now after you have edited the text box and applied the settings the you can simply remove the edit box from there.

```
$(".settings").click(function() {
$("<input/>").attr("class", "editbox")
  .attr("value", "")
  .appendTo($("yourPortletSelector"));
```

});

```
$(".applySettings").click(function {
    //do all your work
    $(".editbox").remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi Digvijay thank you very mch for your reply..but the problem here is that my Editbox has JSF elements that shows Portal details(i.e Portal Height,Width etc) stored in DB which are modified by the user and then again stored in the database file hence I cannot create a dynamic div at runtime.

Comment: For this case you can put your edit box to some other place.
Now when you select any portal the edit box can update its value according to portal properties.
And when you click the apply button the properties are saved back to the database.